# Regexp to match usernames prefixed by "@" character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a method that takes a string that's inputted through a form with the following format:

```
string = "@user1, @user2, @user3"
```

And returns an array like `['user1', 'user2', 'user3']`.

This is what I have so far:

```
usernames = "@user1, @user2"

temp_recipient_usernames = usernames.split(',')
recipient_usernames = temp_recipient_usernames.each do |u|
  u.gsub /@(\w+)/ do |username|
    @final_usernames = username.gsub('@', '')
  end
end

p @final_usernames
```

This only returns the string `"user2"`. How do I get this to work?

Comment: `@final_usernames =` overwrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are somewhat reinventing the wheel, the [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-scan) method is here for exactly your purpose:

```
usernames = "@user1, @user2"
usernames.scan(/(?<=@)\w+/)
# => ["user1", "user2"]
```

**Update**: Given that the `usernames` string always has the exact format you described, i.e. it contains just `@`-prefixed usenames, commas, and spaces; the regexp can be made a little simpler:

```
usernames.scan(/\w+/)
# => ["user1", "user2"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the shortest way, but is conceptually straightforward.

```
"@user1, @user2, @user3"
.split(", ")
.map{|s| s.delete("@")}
# => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

Or,

```
"@user1, @user2, @user3"
.delete("@")
.split(", ")
# => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way :

```
usernames = "@user1, @user2"
usernames.split(/\W/).reject(&:empty?) # => ["user1", "user2"]
```

Comment: `/[^a-z0-9]/i` is almost the same as `/\W/`.

Answer (score 1):

Or this one:

```
"@user1, @user2, @user3".gsub("@","").split(",")
#=> ["user1", " user2", " user3"]
```